# Find the most recent file in a folder/dir and send that file in a email using shell script in windows cmd or powershell

Tags: windows, email, powershell

I need to find the most recent file in a folder/dir and send that file as an attachment in a email, so far i have this code that find the most recent file in my windows SO, but i need to specify a route a find the most recent file there and then send that file in a email so far i have this:

***EDIT 1***:

So far i have this:

This part gives me the last file created in a dir/folder:

```
$dir = "D:\Users\myUser\Desktop\dirTest"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Fullname

$attachment = $latest.Fullname
```

And this send the email  (i'm using yahoo accounts):

```
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "yahooAccountThatSendsTheEmail@yahoo.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "passForThisquestion"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "yahooAccountThatSendsTheEmail@yahoo.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "yahooAccountThatRECIEVESTheEmail@yahoo.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Testing e-mail"
$emailMessage.Body = "email from power shell"

$emailMessage.Attachments.Add( $attachment )  <---- this part gives me problems

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($emailSmtpServer, $emailSmtpServerPort)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($emailSmtpUser, $emailSmtpPass);
$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? Do you get an error message, unexpected behavior, or what?

Comment: Is the e-mail being sent without the attachment, when testing without the attachment line?

Comment: @Jeeva nevermind it worked but now my problem is that when i run the script i need to be signed in my yahho account, is there a way to send it without being signed

Comment: I suspect not really, with the Yahoo SMTP servers. There aren't many publicly accessible auth-free SMTP servers, as you can do bad things with them. You might want to consider running your own SMTP server, or finding creds that you don't mind leaving in the script (creating an account specifically for it isn't such a bad plan, if you want to use a free mail provider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PowerShell, something like this should do alright:

```
function Send-RecentFile {
    param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ })]
        [String] $Path
        )

    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | Sort CreationTime | Select -Last 1
    Write-Output "The most recently created file is $($file.Name)"


    $messageParameters = @{
        From        = "myaccount@mydomain.com"
        To          = "destinationAccount@theirdomain.com"
        Subject     = "title"
        Body        = "message body"
        SMTPServer  = "mail.mydomain.com"
        Attachments = $file.FullName
    }

    Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -Credential (Get-Credential "peopleo@anotherDomain.com")
}
```

If you do want to store the credentials in the file, you might have to do something slightly different with it.

Answer (score 1):

It works now, this is my final script.

This script search the most recent file created in a Dir and it sends that file created  to a email account.

Here is my script it works for me but it takes a few minutes to send the email, thanks for the help

This script do what i wanted, it find the most recent file and send tha file in a email.

```
$dir = "d:\Users\myUser\Desktop\testDir"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Fullname

$attachment = $latest.Fullname


$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "test_sender_mail_account@yahoo.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "MyPassword"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "test_sender_mail_account@yahoo.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "test_receiver_mail_account@gmail.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "My Subject"
$emailMessage.Body = "My body message"

$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($emailSmtpServer, $emailSmtpServerPort)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($emailSmtpUser, $emailSmtpPass);
$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this powershell command.

```
  $Body = “get the information here to show the data with attachement”  
    $dir = "Path\of\the\folder(C:\..\..)"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    $latest.Fullname
    $file = $latest.Fullname
    $EmailFrom = “sender@gmail.com”
    $EmailTo = “receiver@gmail.com”
    $SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
    $EmailSubject = “Enter Your Subject”
    $att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
    $mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
    $mailmessage.from = ($EmailFrom)
    $mailmessage.To.add($EmailTo)
    $mailmessage.Subject = $EmailSubject
    $mailmessage.Body = $Body
    $mailmessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $mailmessage.Attachments.Add($att)
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“sender_username”, “sender_password”);
    $SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
    $att.Dispose()
```